# Pass class method as function argument while maintaining this context

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to pass a class method to `Array.map`. Instead of doing `Array.map(v => this.classMethod(v))` I want to just pass the method like `Array.map(this.classMethod)`. But this does not work.

The problem is that if `classMethod` tries to access a member variable an error is thrown, as `this` seems to have the wrong context.

```js
class Foo {
    private memberVariable: number = 42;

    public bar(){
        return [1,2,3].map(this.classMethod);
    }

    private classMethod(v: number){
        return this.memberVariable * v;
    }
}

console.log(new Foo().bar()); // Throws TypeError: this is undefined
```

Is there a way to pass a class method to a function and still maintain the right `this` context inside the passed method?

Comment: only using `bind`

Comment: `[1,2,3].map(this.classMethod.bind(this))` or `[1,2,3].map(x => this.classMethod(x))` or define `classMethod` as an arrow function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define `classMethod` as an arrow function:

```
private classMethod = (v: number) => {
    return this.memberVariable * v;
}
```

Alternatively leave `classMethod` as it is, and then the caller of the function can use `bind` to specify the `this` context:

```
[1,2,3].map(this.classMethod.bind(this));
```